# Install LSP plugins with .ttl extension in Ubuntu

Tags: plugins, ubuntu-studio, ardour, vst

I would like to install the LSP plugins in Ubuntu Studio 20.10.  I know that Ubuntu Studio already has LSP plugins; however, there are several other plugins that I would like to use.  The plugins, as downloaded from LSP, have a 'ttl' extension.  The other plugins that are installed have an 'so' extension.  My reading of the installation procedures indicates that I should just copy the directory to the correct location and ensure that it has the proper name.  When I did that, the plugins were not visible in Ardour, even after including the subdirectory as a search site.  What should I do to get the proper extension on these plugins (i.e. convert them, install from scratch, etc.).

Comment: I just checked a little bit, I see there are different LSP-plugins, VST-plugins with `.so` in `/usr/lib/vst/...` and LV2-plugins with `.ttl` in `/usr/lib/lv2/lsp-plugins.lv2`. I'd copy the plugin to the latter folder and try if it works then.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know why I did not see that.  They work perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

There exist different types of LSP-plugins:

- VST-plugins with the `.so`-extension are located in `/usr/lib/vst/` and it's subfolders.
- LV2-plugins with the `.lv2`-extension are located in `/usr/lib/lv2`
- LV2-plugins with the `.ttl`-extension are located in `/usr/lib/lv2/lsp-plugins.lv2/`.

Since you downloaded a LV2-plugin with the `.ttl`-extension, just copy it to `/usr/lib/lv2/lsp-plugins.lv2/`, you'll need root-privileges to do so though.